# The Little Typer

Tags: types, racket, pie-lang

In "The Little Typer" book, I am just starting to use DrRacket. From a David Christiansen video, I inputted:

```
(claim two-plus-two-is-four
  (= Nat (+ 2 2) 4))
```

which returned an error:

```
 claim : this function is not defined.
```

Why?

Comment: Do you have `pie` installed and `#lang pie` at the top of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to install `pie`. In DrRacket you can do this with: **File** > **Package Manager...** > **Do What I Mean**, typing `pie` in the package source field, and clicking Install.

Alternatively, if you're using the command line you can install it with the command:

```
raco pkg install pie
```

Second, if you're using DrRacket you need to make sure "Determine Language from Source" is selected at the bottom-left of the window (on the command-line this is the default).

Third, put `#lang pie` at the top of your file.

```
#lang pie

(claim two-plus-two-is-four
  (= Nat (+ 2 2) 4))
```

This still doesn't work because `+` isn't built-in; it can be defined in terms of other things that are built-in (this is discussed on pages 72 - 77 of the book).

Comment: Alright, it's not just me. I couldn't figure out why `(+ 1 2)` wasn't working. The `+` function is peppered throughout the first few chapters and I'm sure it says somewhere that it isn't defined but I must have missed that. Went a little grayer today trying to compute `(+ 1 2)`.